# Stanford CoreNLP remove/stop red information print outs

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford's CoreNLP Java API and while running it prints out information in red.
It just fills up the command lines when i don't want to see it.
is there anyway of disabling this feature?

Example of the red info lines:

```
Searching for resource: StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Searching for resource: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.2 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [3.0 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.7 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.0 sec].
Initializing JollyDayHoliday for sutime
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
Jan 03, 2014 3:52:37 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Ignoring inactive rule: temporal-composite-8:ranges
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.8 sec].
Adding annotator dcoref
Searching for resource: StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Searching for resource: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
Adding annotator parse
Adding annotator dcoref
Searching for resource: StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Searching for resource: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
Adding annotator parse
Adding annotator dcoref
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your program context, you can just drop all text from the error stream's output during corenlp execution.

```
// this is your print stream, store the reference
PrintStream err = System.err;

// now make all writes to the System.err stream silent 
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    public void write(int b) {
    }
}));

// YOUR CODE HERE

// set everything bck to its original state afterwards
System.setErr(err);
```

Comment: What is the command line argument when running the server (StanfordCoreNLPServer) to stop prints to the console?